# Alternating series test conditions?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In Stewart's Calculus book he gives the definition for the alternating series test as

[image: Stewart]

Elsewhere, like in Paul's online math notes, it is given as

[image: Paul]

In Stewart's definition $b_n \gt0$ but in Paul's it is $b_n \geq0$

I was doing a problem in which i was asked to find if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n^2-1}{n^3+1}$ is convergent or divergent. I assumed I wouldn't be able to use the alternating series test here because $b_n$ is 0 when $n=1$ and that the alternating series test only applies when $b_n \gt0$ and not $b_n \geq 0$. I discovered that is not true.

Could someone please explain to me the difference between the two definitions? Does it have to do with the difference in superscripts on the $(-1)$?

Answer (score 1):

In Paul online notes as you mentioned if $b_n=0$ for all $n$ then $\sum a_n$ will be nothing but $0$. Anyway if you want to get rid of $b_n=0$ for $n=1$ then 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n^2-1}{n^3+1}=0+\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n^2-1}{n^3+1}=\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m+1}\frac{(m+1)^2-1}{(m+1)^3+1}.$$

Now you can apply either test you want.

Answer (score 0):

If for some $\bar n$, $b_{\bar n} =0$, then condition (i) implies that $b_n = 0$ for all $n\ge \bar n$, so your sum is actually a finite sum. In that case the theorem would not tell you much!

Anyway, whenever you are asked the monotonicity, you are really interested in it from some point onward, as you can discard finetely many terms without changing the behaviour of the overall series.